# NSDateFromString, parsing a date in the very past

Tags: cocoa-touch, date, date-parsing

I'm executing this code to parse date `01 January 1800`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"01011800"];
```

when I print `date` with

```
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

I get

```
1799-12-31 23:10:04 +0000
```

My expected result is `1799-12-31 23:00:00 +0000`: I'm in central Europe and at 1st January I have a 1.00 hours offset respect to UTC, but I cannot understand where that 10 minutes and 4 seconds come from.

Answer (score 0):

Have a good look on the internet about time zone changes in your area through the last few hundred years. Bets are that the result is actually correct, and that in 1800 your local time zone was off by ten minutes and four seconds.

For a date in 1800, Apple obviously doesn't use what the timezone information is *today*, but what it was 214 years ago.

Comment: I'm confident that Apple calculations are good. I just want to understand from where that data come from